# Proving $H_i(S^n - h(D^k))=0$ $\forall i>0$

Tags: algebraic-topology

In class today we showed that $H_i(S^n - h(D^k))=0$ where $h(D^k)$ is the embedding of the k-disc into $S^n$. The proof was very technical and used induction. I am wondering why the following argument doesn't work:

Since $D^k \cong h(D^k)$ and we know that $D^k$ is contractible we know that $h(D^k)$ is contractible. Thus $H_i(S^n - h(D^k))=H_i(S^n - \{p\})$ and since $S^n - {p}$ is contracible we get $H_i(S^n - h(D^k)=0$  $\forall i>0$

Perhaps we do not know that $h(D^k)$ is contractible because the ambient space may add complications and so we do not know for sure that $S^n - h(D^k) \cong S^n - D^k$ or something like that. Does anyone have any insight, clarification or general remarks on the matter? Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that $H_i(S^n-h(D^k))=H_i(S^n-\{p\})$ using the fact that $h(D^k)$ is contractible ?

Comment: Also be carefull $S^n-D^k$ doesn't really make sens

Comment: By contracting $h(D^K)$ to $\{p\}$ was the idea

Comment: Yes but you are using the fact that the contraction of $h(D^k)$ onto $\{p\}$ implies a contraction of $S^n-p$ onto $S^n-h(D^k)$ right ?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed true and something that I was assuming. I mean, couldn't we like take the inverse of the contraction or something? What makes this complicated to do?

Comment: I don't no if it is complicated to do but I don't know how to do it. Do you have a simple proof ?

Comment: Let $C: h(D^k) \times I \rightarrow h(D^k)$ be a contraction of $h(D^k)$ to a point. Let $R$ be the mapping s.t. it is $C$ except it sends $t \in I$ to $(1-t) \in I$ or something like that. Reverse the contraction ya diG? Oh and it starts with a point and goes to $h(D^k)$ idk something like that hard to type in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92852/discussion-between-adam-chalumeau-and-mathematical-mushroom).

Comment: The image of a contractible space doesn’t have to be contractible. A line is contractible but can wrap around a circle.

Comment: but if we wrap a line around a circle that's not a homeomorphism because we are identifying end points. The case I stated is special because it's an embedding.

Comment: Ok yes I agree with that.

Comment: so my embedded disc is contractible you think? hmm

Comment: In general you don't know if the complement of a contractible space has the same homology type as the complement of a point. For example take $X= \Bbb R ^3$ and consider the complement of $1$ line that passes through the origin and of $2$ lines that pass through the origin.

Comment: thank you! leo lerena!

Comment: @LeoLerena Your example is not compact as $h(D^k)$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you argue that $S^n \setminus h(D^k)$ is homeomorphic (or at least homotopy equivalent) to $S^n \setminus \{ p\}$. However, in general $S^n \setminus h(D^k)$ is not even simply connected. An example is the Alexander horned ball (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere).